# Python - csv.reader prints name of CSV file

Tags: python, csv, urllib

I'm trying to make a program that parses a csv file from Yahoo Finance:

```
import urllib.request
import csv
    def getCsv():
        symbol = input("Enter stock ticker in all caps\n")
        csvUrl = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={0}&a=12&b=1&c=2012&d=12&e=1&f=2013&g=d".format(symbol)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(csvUrl, symbol + "histdata.csv")
    except(urllib.http.HTTPError):
        print("File not found. Try again.\n")
    csvParse(symbol)

def csvParse(symbolData):
    csvRead = csv.reader(symbolData + "histdata.csv")
    for each in csvRead:
        print(each)
        getCsv()
```

If i put in, say GOOG as the symbol, everything downloads, but instead of printing the CSV file, as I thought it will, it instead prints:
['G']
['O']
['O']
['G']
['h']
['i']
['s']
['t']
['d']
['a']
['t']
['a']
['.']
['c']
['s']
['v'],
 as if it were a list.

Comment: Change the 4th to last line to 'csvRead = csv.reader(open(symbolData + "histdata.csv"))'?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I had to open the file first. Apparently, I can't read.